# Refresh ListView when an AsyncTask is inside the Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a ListView and a Custom Adapter. The Custom Adapter implements an AsyncTask to load some images from a server. Everything works fine when the activity is created. However, the ListView has a Load Button to load more rows, each row contains an image. The new data (images) are added properly to the ListView when de Load Button is pressed. However, the ListView is not refreshed despite notifyDataSetChanged is called. I have to move the scoll to refresh the ListView and the new data are displayed. The problem is that the new images are loaded in the AsyncTask inside the Adapter and when notifyDataSetChanged is called in the MainActivity, the AsyncTask is not finished yet. So, my question is: Is there any way to refresh the ListView once the AsyncTask is finished? Calling notifyDataSetChanged inside the Adapter or another alternative?

Comment: implement an `interface` to your `activity` and update that from your `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your asynctask `onPostExecute` it should be something like this:

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   ((MainActivity) getActivity).notifyDataChanged();
  }
```

Depending on how your code is organized you will call `notifyDataChanged()` in some way similar to this one.

Comment: The problem is that notifyDataSetChanged is a method to be used by the Adapter.

Comment: That's ok, call `MyListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`, where `MyListAdapter` is the name of the class of your custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is: Is there any way to refresh the ListView once the AsyncTask is finished?

Yes you can do that :

1. Pass the **ListView** to the **AsyncTask**,
2. override the `onPostExecute()` method,
3. call `notifyDataChanged` in the `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: The problem is that notifyDataSetChanged is a method to be used from the Adapter and I can not pass the Adapter to itself.